# Any difference between (T)value and T(value)?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Any difference between `(T)value` and `T(value)`? For example `(float)3.14` and `float(3.14)`. Which is faster or better?

Comment: `(T)value` casts `value` into T using the C-style cast, which performs 4 different casts, and `T(value)` tries to call constructor of `T` with `value` as argument(This can be known syntax to you if you ever tried calling class constructors)

Comment: So usually the cast should be faster because it is done in compilation, right? float(a) call constructor in running if a is not known in compilation, so it will be slower.

Comment: for types like float, it shouldnt matter I believe(I never tried to look at assembly comparing the two cases)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They have exactly the same effect and meaning:

ISO/IEC 14882:2011 5.2.3 Explicit type conversion (functional notation):

> A simple-type-specifier (7.1.6.2) or typename-specifier (14.6) followed by a parenthesized expression-list constructs a value of the specified type given the expression list. **If the expression list is a single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent** (in definedness, and if defined in meaning) **to the corresponding cast expression** (5.4).

5.4 is "Explicit type conversion (cast notation)", i.e. (T) *cast-expression*.

Comment: Worth noting that for some types (e.g., `char *`), only the `(T) foo` notation is legal.

Comment: @T.C.: for some *notation* not type, as we can still use `typedef` and then use `char_pointer(value)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 True, I should have been more precise. For a type that's denoted by neither a *simple-type-specifier* nor a *typename-specifier*, to be precise.